# Brotli not being served with AWS amplify but gzip files are

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, aws-amplify, brotli

I'm using Aws amplify to host a vue3 app,  I have got webpack bulding the .gz & .br files, have updated my redirect in aws amplify to </^[^.]+$|.(?!(gz|br|css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>

so as gz and br are included.  So gzip file are now being served but its not serving brotli files, the amplify cloudfront is setup to enable both gzip and brotli,  so i'm stumped as to whats wrong, would anyone know why?

Comment: Does the client-side provide brotli in the request headers?

Comment: ye it does: accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br ,content-encoding: gzip

Comment: Based on this open issue (https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/1574), it seems like Amplify doesn't support Brotli yet?